# Prisma with PostGIS: ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/13/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgis, prisma

I am following [this link](https://freddydumont.com/blog/prisma-postgis) to use PostGIS with Prisma.
I added the following model to my prisma.schema:

```
model area{
  id                  Int      @id @default(autoincrement())

  geometry    Unsupported("geometry")
  @@index([geometry], name: "geometry_idx", type: Gist)

  created_at          DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_at          DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
}
```

Then i created a migration and edited it. It looks like this:

```
-- create postgis extension
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "area" DROP COLUMN "coordinates",
ADD COLUMN     "geometry" geometry NOT NULL;

-- CreateIndex
CREATE INDEX "geometry_idx" ON "area" USING GIST ("geometry");
```

Now, when I run `prisma migrate dev --create-only` I get the following error:

```
Error: P3006

Migration `20220925201559_add_postgis_geometry` failed to apply cleanly to the shadow database. 
Error:
db error: ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/13/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
   0: sql_migration_connector::validate_migrations
             at migration-engine/connectors/sql-migration-connector/src/lib.rs:272
   1: migration_core::state::DevDiagnostic
             at migration-engine/core/src/state.rs:250
```

I installed postgis, postgresql-13 and postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts via apt (Ubuntu). `dpkg -l | grep postgresql` gives me:

```
ii  pgdg-keyring                               2018.2                                     all          keyring for apt.postgresql.org
ii  postgresql-13                              13.8-1.pgdg22.04+1                         amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-13-postgis-3                    3.3.1+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                   amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13
ii  postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts            3.3.1+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                   all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13 -- SQL scripts
ii  postgresql-client-13                       13.8-1.pgdg22.04+1                         amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 13
ii  postgresql-client-common                   243.pgdg22.04+1                            all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                          243.pgdg22.04+1                            all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

And `dpkg -l | grep postgis` gives me

```
ii  postgis                                    3.3.1+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                   amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL
ii  postgis-doc                                3.3.1+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                   all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- documentation
ii  postgresql-13-postgis-3                    3.3.1+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                   amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13
ii  postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts            3.3.1+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                   all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13 -- SQL scripts
```

When I run `find /usr -name postgis.control` I get `/usr/share/postgresql/13/extension/postgis.control`, so the file indeed does exist.

What am I missing?

Comment: I found a related issue here: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/13127 could you have a look and check if suggestions mentioned there work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need make and make install pageinspect. Here are the steps to solve the problem:

1. Find the pageinspect dir.

```
$ find / -name pageinspect -print
/root/postgresql-9.2.24/contrib/pageinspect
```

2. Make and make install.

```
[root@bat pageinspect]# make && make install
/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/postgresql/lib'
/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/postgresql/share/extension'
/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/postgresql/share/extension'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 755  pageinspect.so '/usr/local/postgresql/lib/pageinspect.so'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./pageinspect.control '/usr/local/postgresql/share/extension/'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./pageinspect--1.0.sql ./pageinspect--unpackaged--1.0.sql  '/usr/local/postgresql/share/extension/'
```

3. Change owner and group.

```
[root@bat pageinspect]# cd /usr/local/postgresql/lib/
[root@bat lib]# chown -R postgres:postgres pageinspect.so
[root@bat lib]# cd /usr/local/postgresql/share/extension
[root@bat extension]# chown -R postgres:postgres pageinspect--1.0.sql pageinspect.control pageinspect--unpackaged--1.0.sql
```

4. Go psql and create extension.

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION pageinspect;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

5. Show page header info.

```
postgres=# select * from page_header(get_raw_page('tb1', 0));
    lsn    | tli | flags | lower | upper | special | pagesize | version | prune_xid 
-----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+---------+-----------
 0/179EFC0 |   1 |     0 |    36 |  8000 |    8192 |     8192 |       4 |         0
(1 row)
```

Hope to help you.